# Squeak-VM in Ubuntu 12.04 ARM

Tags: 12.04, arm, ac100

There is a Squeak-VM package for Ubuntu 12.04 here: [Squeak-VM armhf binary](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/armhf/squeak-vm/1:4.4.7.2357-1.1ubuntu1).
Using Ubuntu for ARM on my Toshiba AC100 I can't find this package when I search for it with aptitude. Do I have to add additional repositories?

--edit 2012-09-27 20:21--

universe is activated in my sources.list:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-updates restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ precise-security restricted main multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
```

When I search with aptitude, the following packages are found:

```
marc@toshi:~$ sudo aptitude search squeak
v   squeak-image-gz                                                 -                                                                          
p   squeak-image3.9                                                 - Das Squeak-Smalltalk-System (Abbild und Änderungsprotokoll)              
p   squeak-plugin-image                                             - Das Squeak-Smalltalk-System (Abbild und Änderungsprotokoll)              
p   squeak-plugins-scratch                                          - Squeak plugins for the Scratch programming environment                   
p   squeak-plugins-scratch-dbg                                      - Squeak plugins for the Scratch programming environment - debug           
p   squeak-sources3                                                 - Das Squeak-Smalltalk-System (Quelltext)                                  
p   squeak-sources3.9                                               - Das Squeak-Smalltalk-System (Quelltext)
```

I'm still missing squeak-vm :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did a `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/list` and `sudo apt-get update` after that and now aptitude finds the package!